# How to use compilation-database for build?

Tags: c, build, compilation-database

I find tons of descriptions how to generate a compilation database (especially compile_commands.json) for a C/C++ project.
But the other way round: how to use it as input for a build via make or similar from command line?

Comment: You seem to have a chicken & egg problem there.  You need to be able to build the project in order to construct a compilation database.  Once you have a build system that can do that, how is it useful to use the CDB to generate a build system?

Comment: Did you use an IDE to create the compile_commands.json for you?  If you did it probably has the ability to create a makefile too.

Comment: I created the database on Windows (Visual Studio 2019) from given project.sln, want to use it with makefiles or similar on Mac (never ever VS Code). That simple.

Comment: It shouldn't be (too) hard to come up with a script that will parse the JSON and execute the commands.

Comment: Probably not complicated. But I really wonder why compilation is not a normal use case for a COMPILATION-database ;).